# how to combine rows to copy data to missing data rows

Tags: python, pandas

So I have the following dataframe that has extra rows which I want to collapse and copy over the data / replace data into empty cells.

I don't know how to leverage `groupby()` if at all for this usecase.
 this is the pandas  dataframe:

```
id Term                  Course        grade1: grade2: grade:3
 1 Fall 2018-Spring 2019  GEO 302E  -   -   -   
 1 Spring 2019            GEO 302E  -   96  -
 1 Fall 2018              GEO 302E  91  -   91
```

i want the dataframe to collapse this way

```
id Term                  Course        grade1: grade2: grade:3
 1 Fall 2018-Spring 2019  GEO 302E  91  96  N/A
```

Comment: I think one would have to use a bit of regex to match the term names to the individual term columns., few queries, are all the blank values represented with `-`, do all the variables in the `Term` column follow The same format, that is `Season Year - Season Year` ?

Comment: Why the output is `91 96 N/A` not `91 96 91`?